# HTML auto refreshing despite jQuery intercept

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing a website through Parse.com JavaScript. I'm working on the login page and I found this nice template: http://designscrazed.org/css-html-login-form-templates/

However, when I try to modify the submit part of this page to be processed through Parse.com, the page auto-refreshes before the Parse.com transaction could be made. I know the JavaScript file is properly referenced though.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Prindle Login</title>
    <!-- PARSE-->
    <link href="dist/css/login-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/parse/login-js.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="login-card">
    <h1>Prindle Login</h1><br>
  <form id="form">
    <input id="prindle_log_on_username" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
    <input id="prindle_log_on_password" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
    <input id="prindle_log_on" type="submit" class="login login-submit" value="Log In">
  </form>
  <div class="login-help">
    <a href="#">Register</a> • <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
// dynamically adding to a document: http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery/comment-page-1

$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('hello');
    Parse.$ = jQuery;
    Parse.initialize("APP ID", "JS ID")
});

// called when the user clicks the log in button
$('#prindle_log_on').on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("form has been submitted.");
    // perform onclick

    // get the values of the input fields for username and password
    var username = $('#prindle_log_on_username').val();
    var password = $('#prindle_log_on_password').val();

    // try to log in
    Parse.User.logIn(username, password,
        {
            success: function(user) {
                // Do stuff after successful login.
                alert('user found');
            },
            error: function(user, error)
            {
                // The login failed. Check error to see why.
                alert('log in failed');
            }
        });
});
```

I never get the balloon saying "form has been submitted." Help?

EDIT: (thanks to moogs)

```
<div class="login-card">
     <h1>Prindle Login</h1>
    <br>
    <form id="form">
        <input id="prindle_log_on_username" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username">
        <input id="prindle_log_on_password" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
        <input id="prindle_log_on" type="submit" class="login login-submit" value="Log In">
    </form>
    <div class="login-help"> <a href="#">Register</a> • <a href="#">Forgot Password</a>

    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#prindle_log_on').on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("form has been submitted.");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the click handler inside `$(document).ready` because `$('#prindle_log_on')` will not be found until the body has rendered.

**http://jsfiddle.net/moogs/L62z4k5o/1/**

Comment: Didn't seem to change anything :( I'll add an update with what you recommended